# Adding json data into UITableView

Tags: iphone

This is a sample getData method in my viewController.m file

```
-(void) getData {
// Create new SBJSON parser object
SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

// Prepare URL request to download statuses from Twitter
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://twitter.com/statuses/public_timeline.json"]];

// Perform request and get JSON back as a NSData object
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

// Get JSON as a NSString from NSData response
NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

// parse the JSON response into an object
// Here we're using NSArray since we're parsing an array of JSON status objects
NSArray *statuses = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];

// Each element in statuses is a single status
// represented as a NSDictionary
for (NSDictionary *status in statuses)
{
    NSString *text = [status objectForKey:@"text"];
    // You can retrieve individual values using objectForKey on the status NSDictionary
    // This will print the tweet and username to the console
    NSLog(@"%@ - %@", [status objectForKey:@"text"], [[status objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"screen_name"]);

}
}
```

What i want to do is take the `[[status objectForKey:@"user"]`and make make it the name of the cell in the table view, How would i go about doing this?

EDIT: Okay so i got it into a string but now that i try to load it it crashes saying `[__NSCFDictionary isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6892b60'`

and it shows the thread right next to `cell.textLabel.text = [[statusArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"user"];` saying `Thread 1 SIGABRT`

Answer (score 2):

In getData function gather all the data in an array. say it statusArray.
Now, derived a viewcontroller from UItableViewController. Make a member in this class of NSArray type and assign above array to it.
Write below functions into the controller class.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return statusArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [statusArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"user"];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: FYI, `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` returns 1 in `UITableViewController` by default so you don't really need it in your subclass

Comment: Im sorry, Im very new at objective-c . How exactly do i gather it all into an array? Because i tried making an instance variable (probably the wrong thing to do) of statusArray then                NSArray *statuses = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil]; Im sure this is wrong because it did not show anything in my table view.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the [`UITableViewDataSource`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol:

- `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` - return the number of "statuses"
- `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` - return a UITableViewCell whose textLabel.text is set to your text.

There are plenty of examples in Apple's docs, including the project you get when you create a new app using Xcode's "Master-Detail App" template.