# How to use Json arry to UITAbleview

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm using below `JSON` values , i need to show this values to `UITableview`.

Please help me.

```
{"id":"58","appVersionId":"1102","averageRating":"4.0","reviews":{"reviews":[{"id":"58","userId":"1","reviewTitle":"Good application","reviewText":"nice","rating":"4.0","createdDate":"2013-02-11T00:00:00+08:00"},{"id":"102","userId":"252","reviewTitle":"Good","rating":"4.0","createdDate":"2013-02-13T00:00:00+08:00"}]}}
```

Comment: Please search this site for an answer -- a version of this question has been asked and answered hundreds of times.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding json data into UITableView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875641/adding-json-data-into-uitableview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download SBJSon library from [link](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/)

Import thse files

```
 #import "JSON.h"

 #import "SBJsonParser.h"

jsonurl=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://sample.com/sample.php"]; //NSUrl declared in .h

jsondata=[[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:jsonurl encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];//NSData 
jsonarray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; //NSmutableArray

self.jsonarray=[jsondata JSONValue];


 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
     UILabel *description=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, 210,44 )];
     description.text=[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",[[jsonarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey: @"id"]];
     [description setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
     description.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
     description.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
     // description.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:79.0f/255.0f green:66.0f/255.0f blue:55.0f/255.0f alpha:1];
     description.numberOfLines=3;
     [cell.contentView addSubview:description];
}


return cell;

 }
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: why go for an external library when you have NSJSONSerialization.

Comment: @Rakesh  SBJson will be supported in earlier iOS versions too