# How do I bind values in UITableview from a URL using JSON?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have written the code in my application like:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{

    SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];

    NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

    NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSArray *statuses = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];

    for (NSDictionary *status in statuses) {

        NSLog(@"%@ - %@", [status objectForKey:@"Name"], [status objectForKey:@"LoginUrl"] );
    }
}
```

This is my JSON. I just want to get Name,Image,LoginUrl in my UITableView.

**JSON**

**0**

```
Name : "Windows Live™ ID"

LoginUrl : ""

LogoutUrl : ""

ImageUrl : ""

EmailAddressSuffixes
```

**1**

```
Name : "Google"

LoginUrl : ""

LogoutUrl : ""

ImageUrl : ""

EmailAddressSuffixes
```

**2**

```
Name : "Yahoo!"

LoginUrl : ""

LogoutUrl : ""

ImageUrl : ""

EmailAddressSuffixes
```

What should I write in my .m file?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875641/adding-json-data-into-uitableview  You might want to search a bit more before posting a question.

Comment: i tried that but i'm not getting the value,i don't know how to getData function gather all the data in an array,can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, and unlike in OSX, [you do not have Bindings in iOS and Cocoa-touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3812972/is-there-any-data-binding-mechanism-available-for-ios).

I assume that what you are looking for is the standard UITableView population mechanisms, which are achieved by implementing the Datasource and Delegate Methods of the UITableView.

This has been discussed in many threads, but I will remind you the basic strategy.

From your JSON response you haven an Array, each of which contain data necessary to populate a 
UITableCellView. 
In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`: you should check the indexPath row (assuming you have only one section), get the element of the corresponding array, and use that to set the properties of the CellView. It will look like something like this:

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault     reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
 NSDictionary *myJsonResponseIndividualElement = myJsonResponseElementsArray[indexPath.row];
 cell.textLabel.text = myJsonResponseIndividualElement[@"Name"];    
return cell;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple tutorial about parsing JSON and showing in Table View http://www.altinkonline.nl/tutorials/json/xcode-and-parsing-json/

**Note:** parsing is happening in `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` - Dont do this unless you really need to download and parse data every time the view appears